# How can I bind 10 by 10 records from database using jQuery datatable and c# pagemethods?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I am new to jQuery datatable, I want to bind 10 by 10 records from database . I know it is possible, but I don't know how to do. I seen many examples but all examples don't have **startindex** and **endindex** values, also I don't know how the ascending and descending order works, because no parameter pass to server regarding for ascending & descending order.

I seen examples from the below urls
[Using ASP.NET PageMethods with JQuery DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686019/using-asp-net-pagemethods-with-jquery-datatables)
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

I want to works this code like below
**Client side code**

```
PageMethods.bindcompanyDetails(startIndex,EndIndex,bindcompanyDetails_success);

    function bindcompanyDetails_success(result)
    {
        var totalrecordes = result[0].totalrow;
         //What can I write here
    }
```

**Serverside code**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static Array bindcompanyDetails(int startIndex, int EndIndex)
    {
        clssetting setobj = new clssetting();
        return setobj.getalcompanydetails(startIndex,EndIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you make an ajax call for server-side datatable there are a lot of parameter are appended with the URL and these parameter are available at server side. Some of them are:

```
start=0&length=10
```

here `start` and `length` are the parameter that can be used with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to get the required number of result.